# Reportbuilder data set errors with good SQL?

Tags: sql-server, reportbuilder3.0

I have a `bigint` status that has bitwise flag set in it and I am trying to make a report to use this info, my code goes

```
cast(foo.State & 0x0 as bit)&1 as Case1,
cast(foo.State & 0x1 as bit)&1 as Case2,
cast(foo.State & 0x2 as bit)&1 as Case3,
cast(foo.State & 0x4 as bit)&1 as Case4,
cast(foo.State & 0x8 as bit)&1 as Case5,
```

But when I try to combine 2 bits into a unique status it fails,

I have tried:

```
(cast(foo.State & 0x4 as bit) and cast(foo.State & 0x8 as bit)) as CaseBar
```

and also

```
Case foo.State & 0xc when 12 then 1 else 0 end as CaseBar
```

both of these run fine when in a SQL query, but fail inside the reportbuilder dataset properties, any feedback or pointers here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way to make it happen was:

```
cast((cast(foo.State & 0x8 as bit) & Cast(foo.State & 0x4 as bit)) as bit)&1 as CaseBar,
```

the problem was the report-builder engine did not support a full TSQL set of commands